# Hibernate throws "org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection" on entitymanager.flush()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, collections, entity

I am currently working on a medium sized Java project with Hibernate and I have come across what seems to be a rare but quite persistent error. The situation is as follows: I have a Student entity who has a bidirectional many-to-many relation to an Education entity (implemented as a join table on the database) and an Admin entity who is a subclass of Student. My code allows for a Student to be "upgraded" to an Admin by removing the Student from the database, creating a new Admin based on the Student and persisting this Admin. However, whenever this happens, Hibernate throws the following error on EntityManager.flush():

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: domain.Student.enrolledEducations
```

Below you can find the relevant code:

Education class

```
@Entity
public class Education {

...

@ManyToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "education_id")
private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<>();
```

Student class

```
@Entity
public class Student {

....

@ManyToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
private Set<Education> enrolledEducations = new HashSet<>();
```

Admin class

```
@Entity
public class Admin extends Student {

...

public Admin(Student student) {
    this.setId(student.getId());
    this.setFirstName(student.getFirstName());
    this.setLastName(student.getLastName());
    this.setEmail(student.getEmail());
    this.setSalt(student.getSalt());
    this.setSuperAdmin(false);
    this.setEnrolledEducations(student.getEnrolledEducations());
    this.setSessions(student.getSessions());
    this.setManagedEducations(new HashSet<Education>());
}
```

Database methods

```
public Admin upgrade(Person person) {
    Admin admin;
    if (person instanceof Student){
        removeStudent((Student) person);
        admin = new Admin((Student) person);
    }
    else{
        removePerson(person);
        admin = new Admin(person);

    }
    addAdmin(admin); //exception happens here

    return admin;
}

public void addAdmin(Admin admin) {
    manager.getTransaction().begin();

    if(manager.contains(admin)){
        manager.merge(admin);
    }
    else{
        manager.persist(admin);
    }

    manager.flush(); //exception happens here
    manager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Test method

```
@Test
public void getEducationsForAdmin_and_upgrade_to_admin_work_correctly(){

    educationSetup();

    Admin admin1 = facade.upgrade(student1); //exception happens here
    Admin admin2 = facade.upgrade(student2);

    admin1.addNewEducation(education1);
    admin1.addNewEducation(education2);
    admin2.addNewEducation(education1);

    facade.updateAdmin(admin1);
    facade.updateAdmin(admin2);

    Set<Education> educations1 = new HashSet<>(facade.getEducationsForStudent(admin1));
    Set<Education> educations2 = new HashSet<>(facade.getEducationsForStudent(admin2));

    assertTrue("admin 1 does not have exactly 1 education", educations1.size()==1);
    assertTrue("admin 2 does not have exactly 2 educations", educations2.size()==2);
    assertTrue("admin 1 does not have the IT education",educations1.contains(education1));
    assertTrue("admin 2 does not have the IT education",educations2.contains(education1));
    assertTrue("admin 2 does not have the M education",educations2.contains(education2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a problem that both Admin and Student have the same identifier.

Since the Admin is created by calling the new function, it is not in the persistent state, the code

```
manager.contains(admin)
```

will always return false, so it will always go to the manager.persist statement.

Since Admin is a different object with the same identifier, you will get the exception

> Found two representations of same collection

All you need to do is to add

```
manager.delete(person)
```

in your

```
removePerson
```

function. It should solve this problem.